# Pyserial write() hangs

Tags: python, ubuntu-16.04, python-3.6, pyserial

I need to communicate with some device using serial port. I know this device parameters (boudrate etc.). I also know that this device waits untill it receives a new line character (I don't know unix or windows type) and then sends back something in ASCII.

The problem is that when i want to write anything the script hangs. No error occurs, just nothing happens later. It's impossible to print anything or even to close the port.

How can I fix that?

It doesn't work for really basic script. Of course this is no a whole code, just an example to present what is not working.

Sadly, I didn't find any explanation or an answer which works.

I'm working on Ubuntu 16.04

Thanks for your help!

```
import serial

ser = serial.Serial(
port="/dev/NameOfDevice",
baudrate=115200,
bytesize=8,
parity='N',
stopbits=1,
timeout = 0)

ser.open()
print('Port was opened')

ser.write(b'\r\n') #this is a line where it stops working. Different inputs were tried, nothing works.
print('Does it works?')
```

Comment: find any example in any tutorial and try to use it - if it will work then try to do something similar. I didn't work with serial but maybe it is open only for reading, not writing (similar like files in system)

Comment: I actually tried some example codes. Every time it's something wrong when I try to send anything.

Comment: what device do you use ? maybe it is not ready for receiving data, and with `timeout=0` program waits all time for device response.

Comment: The problem is that noone exactly knows what a device is it, and I can't "open" it (i mean, chceck physically). I know it works for sure, because it collects some scientific data and I was using it earlier. Now I need to write a python script to send a comands it waits for, and then receive data it sends.

After receiving "enter" it sends something for sure.

Comment: BTW: computers use three types of "enter" - Linux "\n", Windows "\r\n", old MacOS "\r".

Comment: Pyserial includes a script called miniterm.py which you can run on the command line as a terminal emulation and might help with discovering what is being sent.

Comment: One obvious thing to check is hardware flow control. Does the device use it? Is the cable correctly wired? Try turning off H/W flow control in the serial module, and see if that makes any difference.

Comment: I had the same problem once. and it was caused by some interrupt on my inherent COM(COM1) port then I used USB port with USB to serial converter and it worked okay.

Answer (score 3):

edit: I was a fool before, but now I am certain I am correct.

I ran into the same problem and solved it by adding a "write_timeout":

```
ser = serial.Serial(
port="/dev/NameOfDevice",
baudrate=115200,
bytesize=8,
parity='N',
stopbits=1,
write_timeout = 1,
timeout = 0)
```

Note that this will raise a timeout exception. In my case this is the expected behavior, because I'm checking to see if I can properly connect on the user specified port.

So I suspect you are connecting to something, but it isn't acknowledging your write, and since the default behavior for 'write' is to block until acknowledgement, this is what you see.

See also the api description for the write function:
https://pyserial.readthedocs.io/en/latest/pyserial_api.html